# Solr6.0 (Jetty) vs Solr4.0 (Tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, solr, jetty

Recently upgraded from Solr4.0 (Tomcat) to Solr6.0 (Jetty) and my performance degraded to a very high level.

Issues: My CPU consumption increased to the very high level with the same traffic. Note: My primary query contains lots of ids in not in query which requires CPU.

My Solr setting is the same.

Does it mean Jetty performance is low as compared to tomcat when dealing with high no. of -ve ids ?

Comment: Pretty sure using Jetty for Solr was degraded in Solr 5, it's stand alone now. see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+JettyAlso, when you say 'negative ids', do you mean your query is something like "return everything excluding these ids"?

Comment: @Jayce444 yes "return everything excluding these ids"